# How to deserialize a JSON when having a dynamic root key

Tags: java, json, dynamic

I am facing troubles with this json.

```
{"1234345": [{
   "queue": "XXX",
   "name": "XXXXX",
   "entries": [{
   "points": 54,
   "isInactive": false,
   }],
   "tier": "ASDF"
}]}
```

But it also can have this shape:

```
{
 "1234345": [{
  "queue": "XXX",
   "name": "XXXXX",
   "entries": [{
   "points": 54,
   "isInactive": false,
   }],
   "tier": "ASDF"
}],
 "22683144": [{
  "queue": "XXX",
   "name": "XXXXX",
   "entries": [{
   "points": 54,
   "isInactive": false,
   }],
   "tier": "ASDF"
  }]
}
```

The root key is an array and it can change in each call to the service. Thus its dynamic.

I am getting mad with this. I have heard that the best option to work with dynamic keys is to use a Map. But in this case, how do i name the attribute that will contain that map? and in this case being an array i dont know if it should be a map or how to create the corresponding POJO. Any help?

First i would do is create a class for entries.

```
public class myEntry {
   public String points;
   public String isInactive;
}
```

Then  its container class.

```
public class myObject {
   public String queue;
   public String name,
   public myEntry[] entries;
   public String tier;
}
```

But I am stuck here, i dont know how to continue.

Comment: Ick. Somebody really screwed up their JSON design.

Comment: Okay, can you give an example of how you're planning to use the output? While I'm a big advocate of strong, static typing, this sounds like a case where a Groovy dynamic traversal might be the least painful option.

Comment: "1234345", "22683144" These things should be stored in an array. I agree with @chrylis that this JSON design is not good.

Comment: The root number is not important, I can avoid its use. I dont really need that number. Maybe i should redo the json erasing those keys and read it correctly. Yep, the design is terrible i really dont know why they did this way.

Comment: yehe, but how do i name that array. It wont match with any defined attribute. I cannot create a variable named 1234345, this value will change in each call.

Comment: You can change the JSON? Absolutely do so if you can. It should be `"id": "123456"`.

Comment: i can read the output of the service, and then edit the String in my application. But i thought i could find another way to do it. If i dont have any other option i guess i will go in that direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You always could use a [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). Consider the JSON you posted in your question:

```json
{
  "1234345": [
    {
      "queue": "XXX",
      "name": "XXXXX",
      "entries": [
        {
          "points": 54,
          "isInactive": false
        }
      ],
      "tier": "ASDF"
    }
  ],
  "22683144": [
    {
      "queue": "XXX",
      "name": "XXXXX",
      "entries": [
        {
          "points": 54,
          "isInactive": false
        }
      ],
      "tier": "ASDF"
    }
  ]
}
```

Using Jackson, a popular JSON parser for Java, it could be parsed into a `Map<String,Object>` object:

```java
String json = "{\"1234345\":[{\"queue\":\"XXX\",\"name\":\"XXXXX\",\"entries\":["
            + "{\"points\":54,\"isInactive\":false}],\"tier\":\"ASDF\"}],"
            + "\"22683144\":[{\"queue\":\"XXX\",\"name\":\"XXXXX\",\"entries\":["
            + "{\"points\":54,\"isInactive\":false}],\"tier\":\"ASDF\"}]}";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, Object> map = 
    mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});
```

Instead of [`Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html), you could use POJOs:

```java
public class Foo {

    private String queue;
    private String name;
    private String tier;
    private List<Bar> entries;

    // Getters and setters omitted
}
```

```java
public class Bar {

    private Integer points;
    private Boolean isInactive;

    // Getters and setters omitted
}
```

With Jackson, your code would be like:

```java
String json = "{\"1234345\":[{\"queue\":\"XXX\",\"name\":\"XXXXX\",\"entries\":["
            + "{\"points\":54,\"isInactive\":false}],\"tier\":\"ASDF\"}],"
            + "\"22683144\":[{\"queue\":\"XXX\",\"name\":\"XXXXX\",\"entries\":["
            + "{\"points\":54,\"isInactive\":false}],\"tier\":\"ASDF\"}]}";

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Map<String, List<Foo>> map = 
    mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String, List<Foo>>>() {});
```